# Intel XDK iphone build fail

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, phonegap-build, intel-xdk

Web app and android builds are working fine. but the ios build ends with a

```
An unexpected error occured while attempting to build the application.
```

on the summary screen. Going into the build log, it says

```
** BUILD SUCCEEDED **

Command finished with error code 0: .../Nuro Block Chain Netbanking/platforms/ios/cordova/build --device
```

Here are links to the full logs:

Build log: http://pastebin.com/Cwuru6bS

Summary log: http://pastebin.com/pmBxbnwF

Source code: github.com/urocoin/nuro-intel-xdk

Comment: Try removing all of the plugins to see if that makes a difference in the build results. If that works, add each one back, one at a time, until you determine which one is causing the problem. I'm speculating that there is a problem with the plugins and the build system or a conflict. Also, how large is your application? >50MB can cause problems.

Comment: The application is about 1MB, will try playing with the plugins

Comment: Took off all the plugins and its still the same

Comment: Are you able to build one of the sample apps with iOS?

Comment: Yes, I can build the sample hello world app

Comment: In that case, I suspect it is due to the name of your app. Use only simple alpha and numeric and spaces, nothing else (no commas, hyphens, etc.).

Comment: Hope you provide logo and screen for each size they asked

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution in the intel forum:

https://xdk-software.intel.com/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=8141&start=20

It seems you are not allowed to use '-', '.', or spaces in your application name. As far as I see you are using spaces in your application name.